# IFrame and Flash Ad Z-Index Issue

Tags: javascript, html

To preface, I have looked at previous questions and searched google extensively for an answer to this question and apologize if it has been answered once before and I failed to find it.

My problem is that I have advertisements on my website that load some flash content on TOP of any modal, etc that might popup. It does not matter the z-index of the modal.

These advertisements are wrapped in an `<iframe>`. Inside the Iframe are `<script>` tags that load a js file that loads the advertisement.

The source of the `<iframe>` is cross-domain thus disabling the ability to alter the object parameters that might be loaded to add a `wmode` parameter.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is the old iframe hack:

make an iframe and place it on top of the other iframe (z-index).  Anything you want above the flash goes on top of this new iframe.  The new iframe just has a background of white and is sized to perfectly match your popup/modal/etc.

Comment: My modal is, we'll say, 500px tall and 500px wide and is displayed in the middle of the page. The ad is 250px tall and 300px wide and is displayed on the side of the page. When the modal pops up the bottom right corner is cut from the flash ad being on top. Will this fix work, and how may it be implemented?

Comment: yes, it'll work.  your iframe should be 500x500 and in the exact place as your modal.  it's z-index should be below your modal and above your ad frame.  As for how it's implemented, it depends on how your modal is implemented  :)  There are probably jQuery plugins that do this to match an iframe to a div.